# Should も　be used twice here, or is it an error

Tags: grammar

This is a conversation in my Japanese book:

John: I like Brad Pitt.

Mary: I like Brad Pitt too.

Mary's response is translated as ...

私もBrad Pittもすきです。

Is this correct?
I feel like the second もshould still be a が.
If the translation is correct then why is the が　replaced by a も?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends on context. If you stated that you liked someone (not Brad Pitt), and then someone says they like Brad Pitt -- then this would be correct.

> A: 私はLeonardo DiCaprioがすきです。
>   B: 私はBrad Pittがすきです。
>   A: 私もBrad Pittもすきです。

Without that context it would mean that both you and Brad Pitt also like something (not stated, whatever you're talking about).

Comment: Great , but can you explain why the も　is used twice ? Would it be incorrect to say: '' 私も　Brad Pitt　がすきです ''　?

Comment: Something along the lines of "I, also, like Brad Pitt, too"

Comment: Regarding the two も of the last sentence, the first も means that A also likes actor(s) like B does, whereas the second も means that A also likes Brad Pitt besides LeonardoDiCaprio.